# How to connect to a SQL server linked server in Python

Tags: python, sql-server, linked-server

Normally, when trying to connect to a SQL sever DB in Python, I use the `pyodbc` package like this:

```
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};"
                      "Server=<server-ip>;"
                      "Database=<DB-name>;"
                      "UID=<user-name>;"
                      "PWD=<password>;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;"
                      )
```

However, I don't know how to connect to a **linked server** in Python. If my linked server is called `linked-server` and has a DB called `linked-DB` for example; I have tried the same connection string as above, and changing the database name like this: `"Database=<linked-server>.<linked-DB>;"`, since that's how I query the linked server DB in SSMS. But this doesn't work in Python.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: you can't connect to a linked server's database. You'll need to connect to a different database (in the host system) and then reference the other server using 4 part naming convention.

Comment: or if linked server is already established and your credential has permissions to use in queries it can be queried like: `select * from linkedservername.dbname.schemaname.tablename`

Comment: @AlexanderVolok thank you but as I mentioned in the post I can query the DB in SQL server. The question was how to connect to this linked server in Python.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks, I was hoping there would be a way perhaps through another package like sqlalchemy. If that's the definitive answer, should I answer my own question using your comment, or just leave it like this? Sorry, I'm new here!

Comment: @Lamu Can python connect to a server without imputing a password like you can do with linked server after you set them up?